# Does you tube allow you to host instructional videos for your company?

Tags: youtube

I have several instructional screencasts that I want to put on my web app. My web app charges money to users. I am wondering if YouTube is ok with users uploading these types of videos (how-to video but for a company trying to make money) on their site.

Comment: It seems to be common, see for examples the videos about the Alfresco software: http://www.youtube.com/user/alfresco101

Answer (score 6):

This would seem to be the relevant point from their [terms of service](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms):

> E. you agree not to use the Service (including the YouTube Player) for any of the following commercial uses unless you obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
>   i. the sale of access to the Service
>   ii. the sale of advertising, sponsorships or promotions placed on or within the Service, or Content;
>   iii. the sale of advertising, sponsorships or promotions on any page of an ad-enabled blog or website containing Content delivered via the Service unless other material not obtained from YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the basis for such sales

So as long as you aren't charging your users to access the videos and not selling advertising on the videos you should be OK. However, as you are charging for access to your web application this could be construed as charging for access to the videos.

However, I'm not a lawyer so your best bet would be to contact them and ask them if it's OK.

Comment: It would sound like "my web app charges money" would violate section E(i) explicitly as you are charging money to your clients to view videos which are hosted on YouTube.

Comment: @msanford - that would appear to be the clincher.

Comment: Indeed. And by "you" I was of course referring to bgadoci. You (ChrisF) obviously concluded this yourself.

Comment: But I am not charging the to view the videos. The videos are on the blog (which contains no advertising) and are there to explain to people how to use different features of the site.

Comment: @bgadoci - in that case you should be OK - but check with YouTube for a definitive answer.